# Scroll bar in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, scroll-bars

How can I get a scroll bar in spacemacs?

Simply doing this doesn't seem to have any effect for me:

```
(scroll-bar-mode t)
```

In the past, I *think* I recall enabling it and it having some kind of odd visual effect that didn't really resemble a useful scroll bar, but I can't reproduce that now.

Comment: Are you using Emacs from a terminal?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 no, I'm using emacs in an X window

Comment: Have you tried just using `emacs -Q`? It should start with scroll bars enabled. It might be a problem with your GTK theme or something like that.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 in emacs -Q it works fine: just not in spacemacs